# System.DLLNotFoundException using Xamarin on mac

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, dllnotfoundexception

I'm trying to write an android/iOS, xamarin forms app using visual studio on a mac. 
I can add a nuget package and compile but when I run it (on both iOS and android) I get the `System.DLLNotFoundException.`

This happens with many nuget packages but here's the simplest example....
I create a new multi-platform blank forms app
use .NET Standard
add `System.Data.SQLite.Core` nuget package
add `"using System.Data.SQLite;"` to my `.cs` file

Then I add this line of code anywhere...

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection();
```

and I am getting exception on that line

Where are these libraries stored and how do I get them to deploy with my app when I'm running/debugging?

Comment: The libs are inside the application file. Did you check that you added all the nuget packages needed for SQLite? Oh and maybe try to add the Nuget packes also inside the platform projects

Comment: Hi CDP. Without the wider context of your code, its hard to say exactly what the issue is. My educated guess would be that you haven't added the nuget package to every project in your solution. For example, if you've only added the package to your .NET Standard library you won't get a compile time error because the package is referenced in that assembly, but you'll get a runtime error because the Android or iOS project doesn't also have the correct assembly loaded. Also, check the documentation for the package. It may required you doing some platform specific initialization. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but maybe the nugets you had imported are not designed for the Forms App. Try using *SQLite.Net-PCL*

Comment: You're probably right. When looking at all the packages, how do I know which ones are compatible?

Comment: I don't know if there is any text pointing this out, but always read the documentation and example code. This most of the time indicates which to choose. Tell me if this Nuget solved your issue

Comment: separate question but you may can help...

do you know of a sqlite library that supports the attach database command so I can join tables from 2 different files?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, but I never used SQLite before, so maybe someone else can help you